# CMake `link_directories` for libstdc++.so

Tags: c++, cmake, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

I am using CMake's `link_libraries` code to specify a path to (the folder containing) a particular version of `libstdc++.so`.

Initially, on a 32-bit machine, this worked fine: running `ldd <target>` on a built-but-not-installed executable showed that `libstdc++.so` was pointing to the desired version, and I was able to run `ctest` to execute tests even though the system `libstdc++.so` is older than what the tests require.

When I ported the code to a 64-bit machine, however, the desired `libstdc++.so` path was no longer included in the linked executables. This forces me to (ab)use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to run the project's tests.

I tried to replicate the issue with a small test-case, but I can't get it to include the desired paths on *either* platform, so it's possible that the issue is not related to the 32-bit to 64-bit porting activity. I have, however, commented out the `link_libraries` line when building on the 32-bit platform and confirmed that without it, the desired library path is *not* included. I have also checked many times to ensure that I am specifying a valid path for the desired 64-bit library.

Any idea what else might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about the `RPATH` option: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath

> The basic search order is:[1]
>
> The (colon-separated) paths in the DT_RPATH dynamic section attribute
>   of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not exist. The
>   (colon-separated) paths in the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
>   unless the executable is a setuid/setgid binary, in which case it is
>   ignored.

You can of course set it manually via `CMAKE_[EXE,SHARED,STATIC,MODULE]LINKER__FLAGS`  e.g.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-Wl,-rpath -Wl,/path/to/lib"
```

but there is also a possibility to use CMake itself http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling

Comment: I looked at CMake's native options for manipulating RPath, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set it while building without using the CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH option--but I'd like to keep using the strip-rpath-on-installation feature, if possible. I guess this is probably possible with the manual linker flags option, which I suppose I only need to apply to targets I intend to test locally...but do you have any idea why I might be seeing different behavior in the first place?

Comment: I would guess that the stripping will be performed just for installation, e.g. calling `make install` so you could give it a try anyway. My guess that the first thing is working is just because you got lucky there. May there is some environment variable or something else in `/etc/ld.so.conf/*` which does some magic.

Comment: The option I listed in my previous comment requires me *not* to strip paths upon calling `make install `, but I *do* want installation to strip paths.

Comment: Which means you are not testing with `make test` or `ctest`? I thought this is what you meant by testing. Of course if you call `make install` then the stripped Rpath won't work.

Comment: Yes, I am using ctest for testing. I want the paths to be present in the non-installed binaries run by ctest, but stripped in the installed binaries.